# requirejs ! bootstrap.min is not loading in Magento2

Tags: javascript, magento2.2.2, magento-2.1.7, custom-theme, requirejs-config.js

I am doing theme integretion. I have included the bootstrap.min.js file in requirejs-config.js

in requirejs-config.js file

```
 var config = {

 map: {
    '*': {
        'jqueryjs': 'India_Newtheme/js/jquery',
        'bootstrapmin': 'India_Newtheme/js/vendor/bootstrap.min',
        //'bootstrapselect_min': 'India_Newtheme/js/bootstrap-select.min',            
        'scripts': 'India_Newtheme/js/scripts',
        //'jquery_dtpicker': 'India_Newtheme/js/jquery.simple-dtpicker',
        //'jquery_wizard': 'India_Newtheme/js/jquery.smartWizard',
        'html5shivmin': 'India_Newtheme/js/html5shiv.min',    
       // 'scripts1': 'India_Newtheme/js/scripts1'
    }
},
paths: {            
        'jqueryjs': 'India_Newtheme/js/jquery',
        'bootstrapmin': 'India_Newtheme/js/vendor/bootstrap.min',          
        'scripts': 'India_Newtheme/js/scripts',
        //'jquery_dtpicker': 'India_Newtheme/js/jquery.simple-dtpicker',
       // 'jquery_wizard': 'India_Newtheme/js/jquery.smartWizard',
        'html5shivmin': 'India_Newtheme/js/html5shiv.min',    
       // 'scripts1': 'India_Newtheme/js/scripts1',
       // 'priceform': 'India_Newtheme/js/priceForm',
        'animated': 'India_Newtheme/js/animated'
},
shim: {

'jqueryjs': {
    deps: ['jquery']
},

'bootstrapmin': {
    deps: ['jquery']
},

/*'bootstrapselect_min': {
    deps: ['jquery']
},

'jquery_wizard': {
    deps: ['jquery']
},
'jquery_dtpicker': {
    deps: ['jquery']
},
*/
'scripts': {
    deps: ['jquery']
},

'html5shivmin': {
    deps: ['jquery']
},
/*'scripts1': {
    deps: ['jquery']
},
'priceform':{
    deps: ['jquery']
},*/
'animated':{
    deps: ['jquery']
}}}
```

It is not taking the bootstrap.min file and any other js file at all.How to integrate external js with Magento theme.Kindly help me on this

Answer (score 0):

1. `bootstrap.min.js` should be in : `app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/web/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js`
2. `requirejs-config.js` should be in : `app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/requirejs-config.js`

   ```
   var config = {
       deps: [
           'js/output'
       ],
       paths: {
           'bootstrap': 'Magento_Theme/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min',
       },
       shim: {
           'bootstrap': {
               'deps': ['jquery']
           }
       }
   };
   ```